# Not able to fetch value from one view controller to another

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

Well I have two view controllers..

In controller1 I have a textField

Now My problem is whenever I enter anything in that textField..I want to use that value in view controller 2...

but the value is coming null in viewController 2...I don't know what is going wrong??

I know I am making silly mistake but what is that??
can anyone help me here?

This is the code of my viewController 2 's .m file

```
- (void) save_Clicked:(id)sender {

[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

textName=txtCoffeeName.text;
rootViewController.nameValue=textName;
NSLog(@"%@",textName);
}
```

well here I want to use the value of nameValue in rootViewController...which is showing me null..:(
rootViewController is the object of RootViewController which is declared in .h file and textName is the string which is declared too

Comment: @rathodrc : what is the output of NSLog(@"%@",textName); statement ?

Comment: @jhaliya...it is the same value that I am entering in textfield named txtCoffeeName.text

Comment: @rathodrc : nameValue this the property of rootViewController, Are you retaining it OR just assigning ...?

Comment: @jhaliya..I am retaining it at RootViewController

Comment: @ rathodrc : Where are to display this value. What is nameValue . is that NSString or UITexttField. Try to display the value in viewdidAppear Methos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do 2 things

1. property and synthesize of your nameValue in your root view controller
2. modify your code as below

-(void) save_Clicked:(id)sender {

textName=txtCoffeeName.text;

rootViewController.nameValue=textName;

NSLog(@"%@",textName);

[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

Answer (score 0):

please set synthesize property as retain for rootViewController.nameValue,textName.you have to use as self.rootViewController.nameValue,self.textName...I think it will solve your problem..